# How to update row selected by id column?

Tags: java, database, crud

This a 'form'with textfields where admin can update

```
    //For Update
public AdminCreateQnsPanel(JFrame mf, QuizDetails q, int set, String topic) {
    super(mf);

    System.out.println("**** admin create qns panel *"+ q.getQuestionNo());
    System.out.println("**** admin create qns panel *"+ q.getQuestionDesc());
    System.out.println("**** admin create qns panel *"+ q.getOption1());
    System.out.println("**** admin create qns panel *"+ q.getOption2());    

    JLabel lblSet = new JLabel("Set 1");
    lblSet.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 30));
    lblSet.setBounds(29, 160, 141, 28) ;
    add(lblSet);

    JLabel lblQnsDesc = new JLabel("Question Description :");
    lblQnsDesc.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 16));
    lblQnsDesc.setBounds(76, 270, 181, 20);
    add(lblQnsDesc);

    txtfQnsDesc = new JTextField();
    txtfQnsDesc.setColumns(10);
    txtfQnsDesc.setBounds(76, 306, 639, 26);
    add(txtfQnsDesc);
    txtfQnsDesc.setText(q.getQuestionDesc());

    JLabel lblOp1 = new JLabel("Option 1 :");
    lblOp1.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 16));
    lblOp1.setBounds(76, 365, 103, 20);
    add(lblOp1);

    txtfOp1 = new JTextField();
    txtfOp1.setColumns(10);
    txtfOp1.setBounds(218, 362, 146, 26);
    add(txtfOp1);
    txtfOp1.setText(q.getOption1());

    JLabel lblOp2 = new JLabel("Option 2 :");
    lblOp2.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 16));
    lblOp2.setBounds(76, 418, 103, 20);
    add(lblOp2);

    txtfOp2 = new JTextField();
    txtfOp2.setColumns(10);
    txtfOp2.setBounds(218, 415, 146, 26);
    add(txtfOp2);
    txtfOp2.setText(q.getOption2());

    JLabel lblOp3 = new JLabel("Option 3 :");
    lblOp3.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 16));
    lblOp3.setBounds(76, 468, 103, 20);
    add(lblOp3);

    txtfOp3 = new JTextField();
    txtfOp3.setColumns(10);
    txtfOp3.setBounds(218, 465, 146, 26);
    add(txtfOp3);
    txtfOp3.setText(q.getOption3());

    JLabel lblOp4 = new JLabel("Option 4 :");
    lblOp4.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 16));
    lblOp4.setBounds(76, 515, 103, 20);
    add(lblOp4);

    txtfOp4 = new JTextField();
    txtfOp4.setColumns(10);
    txtfOp4.setBounds(218, 512, 146, 26);
    add(txtfOp4);
    txtfOp4.setText(q.getOption4());

    JLabel lblCorrAns = new JLabel("Correct Answer :");
    lblCorrAns.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 16));
    lblCorrAns.setBounds(76, 581, 151, 20);
    add(lblCorrAns);

    txtfCorrAns = new JTextField();
    txtfCorrAns.setColumns(10);
    txtfCorrAns.setBounds(218, 578, 146, 26);
    add(txtfCorrAns);
    txtfCorrAns.setText(q.getCorrectAnswer());

    JButton button = new JButton("Add");
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            actionPerformedAdd();
            //actionPerformedOk();

        }
    });

    button.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 16));
    button.setBounds(428, 622, 115, 29);
    add(button);

    JButton btnCancel = new JButton("Cancel");
    btnCancel.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            JPanel contentPane = new AdminQuizOverallPanel(myFrame, set, topic);
            myFrame.setContentPane(contentPane);
            myFrame.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
    btnCancel.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 16));
    btnCancel.setBounds(712, 622, 115, 29);
    add(btnCancel);

    JLabel lblQnsNo = new JLabel("Question No. : ");
    lblQnsNo.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 16));
    lblQnsNo.setBounds(76, 234, 151, 20);
    add(lblQnsNo);

    txtfQnsNo = new JTextField();
    txtfQnsNo.setBounds(218, 228, 146, 26);
    add(txtfQnsNo);
    txtfQnsNo.setColumns(10);
    txtfQnsNo.setText(new Integer(q.getQuestionNo()).toString());


    JButton btnUpdate = new JButton("Update");
    btnUpdate.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            actionPerformedUpdate();


    } });
    btnUpdate.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 16));
    btnUpdate.setBounds(572, 622, 115, 29);
    add(btnUpdate);

}




//Create 
private void actionPerformedAdd() {
    // retrieve the user input from the text box/area provided
    if (validateInput()) {
        //amtSpend = Double.parseDouble(txtAmount.getText());
        // create an object of expenses based on the input values
        //Debugging? -> System.out.println(topic);

        //***Refer to QuizDetails Entity Class for its constructor
        QuizDetails e1 = new QuizDetails(Integer.parseInt(txtfQnsNo.getText()), txtfQnsDesc.getText(), txtfOp1.getText(),
        txtfOp2.getText(), txtfOp3.getText(), txtfOp4.getText(), txtfCorrAns.getText(), topic, set);
        // insert to database and check return value
        if (QuizDetailsDA.createQuizDetails(e1)) { //Call Create method from QuizDetailsDA 
            System.out.print("Ok");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(myFrame,
                    "Record created successfully", "Alert",
                    JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            // reset text field for next record.
            txtfQnsNo.setText("");
            txtfQnsDesc.setText("");
            txtfOp1.setText("");
            txtfOp2.setText(""); 
            txtfOp3.setText("");
            txtfOp4.setText("");
            txtfCorrAns.setText("");
            JPanel contentPane = new AdminQuizOverallPanel(myFrame, set,topic);
            myFrame.setContentPane(contentPane);
            myFrame.setVisible(true);
        } else
        {
            System.out.print("Error");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(myFrame,
                    "Database Error. Record not created.", "Alert",
                    JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE); 
        }


    }
}

private boolean validateInput() {
    boolean result = false;
    String msg = "";
    result = true;
    /*int msgType = JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE;

    // retrieve the user input from the text box/area provided
    String dateSpend = txtDate.getText();
    String cat = txtCategory.getText();
    String amt = txtAmount.getText();
    String cont = txtContent.getText();

    if (dateSpend.length() != 10)
        msg += "Please enter date in DD-MM-YYYY format.\n";
    if (cat.length() == 0)
        msg += "Please enter category.\n";
    try {
        Double.parseDouble(amt); // convert to double for amount
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        msg += "Plese enter amount in decimal numbers.\n";
    }
    if (cont.length() == 0)
        msg += "Please enter content.\n";

    if (msg.length() == 0)
        result = true;
    else
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(myFrame, msg, "Alert", msgType);
        */
    return result;
}


//Update
public AdminCreateQnsPanel(JFrame mf,String action, QuizDetails e1){
    this(mf, action);
    txtfQnsNo.setText(new Integer(e1.getQuestionNo()).toString());
    txtfQnsDesc.setText(e1.getQuestionDesc());
    txtfOp1.setText(e1.getOption1());
    txtfOp2.setText(e1.getOption2());
    txtfOp3.setText(e1.getOption3());
    txtfOp4.setText(e1.getOption4());
    txtfCorrAns.setText(e1.getCorrectAnswer());
    quizdetails = e1;
}




public AdminCreateQnsPanel(JFrame mf, String action) {
    super(mf);
}



public void actionPerformedUpdate(){
    int qnsNo = Integer.parseInt(txtfQnsNo.getText());
    String qnsDesc = txtfQnsDesc.getText();
    String op1 = txtfOp1.getText();
    String op2 = txtfOp2.getText();
    String op3 = txtfOp3.getText();
    String op4 = txtfOp4.getText();
    String corrAns = txtfCorrAns.getText();

    //***Refer to QuizDetails Entity Class for its constructor 
    QuizDetails e1 = new QuizDetails(id1,qnsNo, qnsDesc, op1, op2, op3, op4, corrAns); 

    //Testing -> System.out.println("action performed update " + e1.getQuestionNo());

    if(QuizDetailsDA.updateQuizDetails(e1)){ //Call Update method from QuizDetailsDA 
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(myFrame,  "Record updated successfully", "Alert", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        txtfQnsNo.setEditable(false);
        txtfQnsDesc.setEditable(false);
        txtfOp1.setEditable(false);
        txtfOp2.setEditable(false);
        txtfOp3.setEditable(false);
        txtfOp4.setEditable(false);
        txtfCorrAns.setEditable(false);


    }
    else{
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(myFrame,  "Database Error. Record not updated.", "Alert", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```

This is the class where JTable is shown.

```
package studyHelperApp.ui;


import javax.swing.JLabel;



import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import model.QuizDetailsTableModel;
import studyHelperApp.dataAccess.QuizDetailsDA;
import studyHelperApp.entity.QuizDetails;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import studyHelpersApp.ui.MasterPanel;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import javax.swing.ListSelectionModel;
import java.awt.Color;




public class AdminQuizOverallPanel extends MasterPanel {
   private JTextField txtfSearch;
   private JTable table;
   private int set;
   private String topic;
   public static int id1;
   private int id;

   private void setTableModelFromDB(){
       ArrayList <QuizDetails> result = QuizDetailsDA.retrieveAllQuizDetails(set,topic); //Call method from QuizDetailsDA
       QuizDetailsTableModel model = new QuizDetailsTableModel(result);
       table.setModel(model);
   }

   public void loadDataTable(){
          setTableModelFromDB();

        } 

    /**
     * Create the panel.
     * @wbp.parser.constructor
     */

   public AdminQuizOverallPanel(JFrame mf) {
        super(mf);
        initComponents();

        setBounds(100, 100, 900, 750);
        setLayout(null);

        JLabel lblDisplay = new JLabel("");
        lblDisplay.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 17));
        lblDisplay.setBounds(550, 200, 287, 20);
        add(lblDisplay);

        JLabel lblSet = new JLabel("Set ");
        lblSet.setBounds(49, 189, 58, 31);
        lblSet.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 30));
        add(lblSet);


        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        scrollPane.setBounds(15, 246, 847, 225);
        add(scrollPane);

        table = new JTable();
        loadDataTable();
        scrollPane.setViewportView(table);


        JButton btnDelete = new JButton("Delete");
        btnDelete.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                actionPerformedDelete();



        }
         });

        btnDelete.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 16));
        btnDelete.setBounds(637, 502, 115, 29);
        add(btnDelete);


        JButton btnSearch = new JButton("Search");
        btnSearch.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 16));
        btnSearch.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0){
                lblDisplay.setText("You searched for: "+txtfSearch.getText());


            }


        });

        btnSearch.setBounds(744, 160, 93, 29);
        add(btnSearch);

        txtfSearch = new JTextField();
        txtfSearch.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                if(e.getKeyCode()== KeyEvent.VK_ENTER)
                lblDisplay.setText("You searched for: "+txtfSearch.getText());
            }
        });
        txtfSearch.setBounds(550, 161, 194, 26);
        add(txtfSearch);
        txtfSearch.setColumns(10);

        JButton btnUpdate = new JButton("Update");
        btnUpdate.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                actionPerformedUpdate();
            }
        });
        btnUpdate.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 16));
        btnUpdate.setBounds(372, 502, 115, 29);
        add(btnUpdate);

        JButton btnAdd = new JButton("Add");
        btnAdd.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                JPanel contentPane = new AdminCreateQnsPanel(myFrame, set ,topic);
                myFrame.setContentPane(contentPane);
                myFrame.setVisible(true);

            }
        });
        btnAdd.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 16));
        btnAdd.setBounds(135, 502, 115, 29);
        add(btnAdd);

        JButton btnBack = new JButton("<Back");
        btnBack.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 16));
        btnBack.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                JPanel contentPane = new AdminQuizSetNoPanel(myFrame, topic);
                myFrame.setContentPane(contentPane);
                myFrame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        btnBack.setBounds(70, 555, 115, 29);
        add(btnBack);

        JLabel lblQuizID = new JLabel(topic);
        lblQuizID.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 30));
        lblQuizID.setBounds(156, 189, 147, 31);
        add(lblQuizID);

        JLabel lblSetNo = new JLabel("");
        lblSetNo.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 30));
        lblSetNo.setBounds(107, 189, 31, 31);
        add(lblSetNo);


        }


    public AdminQuizOverallPanel(JFrame mf, int set, String topic) {
        super(mf);
        this.set = set;
        this.topic = topic;
        initComponents();

        setBounds(100, 100, 900, 750);
        setLayout(null);

        JLabel lblDisplay = new JLabel("");
        lblDisplay.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 17));
        lblDisplay.setBounds(550, 200, 287, 20);
        add(lblDisplay);

        JLabel lblSet = new JLabel("Set");
        lblSet.setBounds(49, 189, 93, 31);
        lblSet.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 30));
        add(lblSet);


        JLabel lblSetNo = new JLabel(Integer.toString(set));
        lblSetNo.setBounds(107, 189, 31, 31);
        lblSetNo.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 30));
        add(lblSetNo);


        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        scrollPane.setBounds(15, 246, 847, 225);
        add(scrollPane);

        table = new JTable();
        loadDataTable();
        scrollPane.setViewportView(table);


        JButton btnDelete = new JButton("Delete");
        btnDelete.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                actionPerformedDelete();



        }
         });

        btnDelete.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 16));
        btnDelete.setBounds(611, 502, 115, 29);
        add(btnDelete);


        JButton btnSearch = new JButton("Search");
        btnSearch.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 16));
        btnSearch.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0){
                lblDisplay.setText("You searched for: "+txtfSearch.getText());
                //findQuizDetails();

            }


        });

        btnSearch.setBounds(744, 160, 93, 29);
        add(btnSearch);

        txtfSearch = new JTextField();
        txtfSearch.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                if(e.getKeyCode()== KeyEvent.VK_ENTER)
                lblDisplay.setText("You searched for: "+txtfSearch.getText());
            }
        });
        txtfSearch.setBounds(550, 161, 194, 26);
        add(txtfSearch);
        txtfSearch.setColumns(10);

        JButton btnUpdate = new JButton("Update");
        btnUpdate.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                actionPerformedUpdate();
            }
        });
        btnUpdate.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 16));
        btnUpdate.setBounds(365, 502, 115, 29);
        add(btnUpdate);

        JButton btnAdd = new JButton("Add");
        btnAdd.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                JPanel contentPane = new AdminCreateQnsPanel(myFrame, set ,topic);
                myFrame.setContentPane(contentPane);
                myFrame.setVisible(true);

            }
        });
        btnAdd.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 16));
        btnAdd.setBounds(123, 502, 115, 29);
        add(btnAdd);


        JButton btnBack = new JButton("<Back");
        btnBack.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 16));
        btnBack.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                JPanel contentPane = new AdminQuizSetNoPanel(myFrame, topic);
                myFrame.setContentPane(contentPane);
                myFrame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        btnBack.setBounds(70, 555, 115, 29);
        add(btnBack);

        JLabel lblQuizID = new JLabel(topic);
        lblQuizID.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 30));
        lblQuizID.setBounds(156, 189, 147, 31);
        add(lblQuizID);

        }





    private void initComponents() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    //Delete
    public void actionPerformedDelete(){

        System.out.println("performed delete 1****");

        int rowSelected = table.getSelectedRow();

        System.out.println("performed delete 2 *****"+ rowSelected);

        if(rowSelected >= 0){
            int resp = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(myFrame, "Confirm Delete?", "Confirmation", JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION);
            if(resp == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
                int selRowDel = (Integer)table.getModel().getValueAt(rowSelected, 0);
                QuizDetailsDA.deleteQuizDetails(selRowDel); //Call Delete method from QuizDetailsDA 
                //QuizDetailsDA.retrieveAllQuizDetails();
                setTableModelFromDB();
            }

            else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(myFrame, "No record selected", "Alert", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }

        }
    }



    //Update
    public void actionPerformedUpdate(){
        int rowSelected = table.getSelectedRow();
        if(rowSelected >= 0){
            int id = (Integer)table.getModel().getValueAt(rowSelected, 0);
            id1 = id;

            QuizDetails quizdt = QuizDetailsDA.retrieveQuizDetailsById(id);
            //Testing -> System.out.println("**** action performed update **: " + quizdt.getQuestionNo());



            //Call method from AdminCreateQnsPanel(JFrame mf, QuizDetails q, int set, String topic) constructor
            JPanel contentPane = new AdminCreateQnsPanel(myFrame,quizdt, set, topic);
            //After adding set and topic to this above constructor, cancel button is working in AdminCreateQnsPanel
            myFrame.getContentPane().removeAll();
            myFrame.setContentPane(contentPane);
            myFrame.setVisible(true); 



        }

        else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(myFrame, "No record selected", "Alert", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }

    } 


}
```

Data access package

```html
//retrieve quiz by id
    public static QuizDetails retrieveQuizDetailsById(int id) {
        // declare local variables
        QuizDetails quizdetails = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        DBController db = new DBController();
        String dbQuery;
        PreparedStatement pstmt;
        // step 1 - connect to database
        db.getConnection();

        // step 2 - declare the SQL statement
        dbQuery = "SELECT * FROM QuizDetails WHERE id=?";
        pstmt = db.getPreparedStatement(dbQuery);

        // step 3 - execute query
        try {
            pstmt.setInt(1,id);
            rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
            if (rs.next()) { // first record found
                quizdetails = convertToQuizDetails(rs);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        // step 4 - close connection
        db.terminate();
        return quizdetails;
        }


    private static QuizDetails convertToQuizDetails(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
        QuizDetails quizdetails;
        int id = rs.getInt("id");
        //String quizID = rs.getString("quizID");
        //int setNo = rs.getInt("setNo");
        int questionNo = rs.getInt("questionNo");
        String questionDesc = rs.getString("questionDesc");
        String option1 = rs.getString("option1");
        String option2 = rs.getString("option2");
        String option3 = rs.getString("option3");
        String option4 = rs.getString("option4");
        String correctAnswer = rs.getString("correctAnswer");



        quizdetails = new QuizDetails(id, questionNo, questionDesc, option1, option2, option3, option4, correctAnswer );

        return quizdetails;
   }


//Update
        public static boolean updateQuizDetails(QuizDetails quizdt) {
            //declare local variables
            boolean success = false;
            DBController db = new DBController();
            String dbQuery; 
            PreparedStatement pstmt;

            System.out.println("quiz details da ** 1a " + quizdt.getQuestionNo());
            System.out.println("quiz details da ** 1b " + quizdt.getQuestionDesc());

            //step 1 - establish connection to database
            db.getConnection();     

            //step 2 - declare the SQL statement
            //dbQuery = "UPDATE QuizDetails SET quizID = ?, setNo = ?, questionNo = ?, questionDesc = ?, option1 = ?, option2 = ?, option3 = ?, option4 =?, correctAnswer = ? WHERE id = ?";

            dbQuery = "UPDATE QuizDetails SET questionNo = ?, questionDesc = ?, option1 = ?, option2 = ?, option3 = ?, option4 =?, correctAnswer = ? WHERE id= ?";
            pstmt = db.getPreparedStatement(dbQuery);

            System.out.println("quiz details da 2 ** " + quizdt.getQuestionNo());

            //step 3 - to update record using executeUpdate method
            try {
                //pstmt.setInt(1, quizdt.getId());
                //pstmt.setString(1, quizdt.getQuizID());
                //pstmt.setInt(2, quizdt.getSetNo());
                pstmt.setInt(1, quizdt.getQuestionNo());
                pstmt.setString(2, quizdt.getQuestionDesc());
                pstmt.setString(3, quizdt.getOption1());
                pstmt.setString(4, quizdt.getOption2());
                pstmt.setString(5, quizdt.getOption3());
                pstmt.setString(6, quizdt.getOption4());
                pstmt.setString(7,quizdt.getCorrectAnswer());
                pstmt.setInt(8, quizdt.getId()); //Cannot be hard coded

                System.out.println(quizdt.getId());
                System.out.println("quiz details da 3 ** " + quizdt.getQuestionNo());

                if (pstmt.executeUpdate() == 1)
                    success = true;
                pstmt.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            //step 4 - close connection

            db.terminate();

            return success;     

        }
```

For instance, I would want to update id 1 and it is updated successfully. However, when I want to update id 5 the updated items of id 5 would be then updated to id 1. Anyone encountered this problem while trying to update database?

Comment: Any suggested codes for me to solve the problem above? :)

Comment: Usually the SQL-code to update is
update TABLE set COLUMN = Value where CONDITION
probably your where condition is not correct.

Comment: WHERE id=? so id =? is my Condition? Pardon me as im new to SQL@Fredy Fischer

Comment: please provide some sample code that you have tried

Comment: Because your ID are wrong so it will update to wrong item

Comment: @sa77 I have added in  the codes on only updated. Because when I row select by id , my id  is wrong as what John has said

Comment: I prefer you post your whole class code.

Comment: @JohnJoe I have tried to post the codes related to update already.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably provide more information for such question. It is hard to understand what is the context You are making update at. For example if You are using MySQL then You can solve this by fixing the query. Id should be used in where part and not in set part. Something like this should work fine:

```
UPDATE TABLE `users` SET `name` = 'John' WHERE `id` = 1;
```

Comment: leave TABLE awy, it is 
    update users set name = 'John' where id = 1